# Playing Skyrim on Dual Screen Setup?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have recently upgraded my PC to a dual-screen setup. One of my monitors is now 1920x1080 and the other is 1280x1024.

I would like to play Skyrim on the 1920x1080 monitor, while doing web browsing, etc on the second monitor - in a way similar to how SW:TOR works with dual screen systems.

I've looked in the options, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to accomplish this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Run Skyrim in windowed mode.

Or, if you don't like the bars on the window, you can try:

- The [borderless windowed mod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=4).

Comment: +1 thanks... the Windowed mode doesn't play well with a full screen resolution. I'll look into the mod.

Comment: My setup has 3 monitors. Please just be aware that removing and giving Skyrim focus can just cause it to give up and quit... Save Often.